# Dynamic Memory and assignment operator overloading of objects

Tags: c++, object, memory, dynamic, assignment-operator

If I'm using an assignment operator overload with dynamic memory should I check to see if there's something inside the pointer already?

for example if object A has a dynamic memory allocation in the constructor for an array called "name".

stored in object A is the name "John" with the memory allocated in the constructor through

```
name = new char[strlen(userinput)+1];
```

If I wanted to copy object B into object A through an assignment operator overload would I have to write

```
if(name != null){delete [] name;}
name = new char[strlen(src.name)+1];
```

To first clear the array out or do I not have to delete name before reallocating memory?

Comment: One `delete[]` per `new[]`, and no need for a null check.

Comment: If you are juggling with dynamically allocated memory, there's probably more to fix than what you're asking for. I'd seriously recommend using a `std::vector<char>` instead of struggling `new/delete` yourself.

Comment: @user3551329 you don't actually have to test `if(name != nullptr)`, since deleting a `nullptr` is a no-op. Just `delete[] name;` should do.

Answer (score 2):

> *"To first clear the array out or do I not have to delete name before reallocating memory?"*

This way, you have to take care about memory management and de-/allocation all the time. You have to obey for copy constructions, assignments also (see [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

> ```
> if(name != nullptr){delete [] name;}
>         // ^^^^^^^ The correct term is nullptr
> ```

You have to manage the `nullptr` value yourself. `delete`/`delete []` don't assign a `nullptr` value automatically, but leave you with a [*dangling pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

---

The better solution instead of managing dynamically allocated memory yourself, is to use an appropriate container class like `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`:

```
class A {
    std::string name;
};
```